# Find all elements based on Root Parent and drawing an HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html

My code is as follows:

```
class GlobalInfo {
     // multiple properties here
}

class RegionalInfo extends GlobalInfo {
    // multiple properties here
    GlobalInfo parent;
}

class BankInfo extends GlobalInfo {
    // multiple properties here
    GlobalInfo parent;
}
```

There could be multiple BankInfo in one RegionalInfo. And there could be multiple RegionalInfo parents inside a BankInfo object.

For e.g.,

```
BankInfo == Bank Of America

RegionalInfo == Dallas // 1st parent

RegionalInfo == Texas // Dallas's parent

RegionalInfo == MidWest // Texas's parent and final parent.
```

Per above example, the immediate parent of BankInfo object points to Dallas, and it's parent points to Texas and then it's parent point to MidWest.

In some cases, there maybe only one or two parents

For e.g.,

```
BankInfo == University Credit Union

RegionalInfo == Houston
```

So for e.g., a tree view from the Root Parent will look something like,

```
<MidWest>
   <Independent Bank Of MidWest/>
   <Midland Bank Of America/>
   <Texas>
      <Bank Of America>
      <Chase Bank>
      <Wells Fargo>
      <Austin>
         <Supereme National Bank>
         <Master Chanse Bank>
         <Austin East>
            <National Bank Of Austin>
            <Federal Bank>
         </Austin East>
      </Austin>
    </Texas>
   <Arizona></Arizona>
   <Kansas>
      <Federal Credit Union>
      <Kansas State Bank>
      <Wichita>
         <State Bank of Kansas>
         <Wichita Credit Union>
      </Wichita>
   </Kansas>
   <Missouri>
      <Bank of St Louis>
   </Missouri>
   <Kentucky></Kentucky>
   <Iowa></Iowa>
</MidWest>
```

The places are objects of **RegionalInfo** and bank's are objects of **BankInfo**.

The challenge here is, as you see there's a possibility of more RegionalInfo objects inside one RegionalInfo object.

I want to come up with an optimized logic to go through all children from the Root Parent and draw a HTML using **ol** and **li** elements.

So a sample HTML tags will look like something below.

```
<li>
            <label for="folder1">MidWest</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="#">Independent Bank Of MidWest</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="#">Midland Bank Of America</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder1">Texas</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Bank Of America</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Chase Bank</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Wells Fargo</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="subsubfolder1">Austin</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subsubfolder1" /> 
                            <ol>
                                <li class="file"><a href="">Supereme National Bank</a></li>
                                <li class="file"><a href="">Master Chanse Bank</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="subsubfolder2">Austin East</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subsubfolder2" /> 
                                    <ol>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">National Bank Of Austin</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Federal Bank</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
```

The above HTML is incomplete. But hope that gives you an idea.

I am struggling to come up with a better logic to do this iteration through each child element by avoiding multiple loops.